# Nodejs - how to make functions happen just once?

Tags: node.js

I got a simple chat app utilizing socket.io and express framework, below is part of the code:

```
var app = express.createServer();
var socket = io.listen(app);

var store = new express.session.MemoryStore;
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
    secret: 'something', 
    store: store, 
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 60*60*24*30*1000
    }
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        req.session.ioid = client.sessionId;
        req.session.channel = req.param('channel');
        req.session.username = req.param('username');
        //I want the code below happen just once                
        res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.send({sid:req.session.id});
    });
});
```

You can see  the res.header and res.send in the socket.on closure. Those "res" will execute constantly, and cause error  "Can't set headers after they are sent."

I'm looking for a way to make the block-

```
res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

res.send({sid:req.session.id});
```

-happen just once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    socket.on("connection", function(client) {
        req.session.ioid = client.sessionId;
        req.session.channel = req.param('channel');
        req.session.username = req.param('username');
    });

    socket.once('connection', function(client) {
        //I want the code below happen just once                
        res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.send({sid:req.session.id});
    });
});
```

Use [`.once`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/events.html#emitter.once)

Comment: @maerics to please your pedantry I've wrapped the entire thing in the get

Comment: Can you clear a bit my understanding on related subject, why in this snippet you wrap those socket event listener binders in `get /` at all?
As i understand socket.on just adds event listeners to listen on any socket connections, therefore all this snippet looks like "do not listen on this socket event until someone will try to get '/'" but then it will continue to listen to events of other users no matter what they are trying to get, and will spawn even more event listeners as someone will try to get '/'
It seems that i misunderstood something completly...

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the response headers out of the connection callback and into the "get /" callback:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        req.session.ioid = client.sessionId;
        req.session.channel = req.param('channel');
        req.session.username = req.param('username');
    });
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.send({sid:req.session.id});
});
```

But the sequencing seems strange in your example.  If you add a connection callback to the socket each time a new request is handled then you'll get a bunch of (potentially) conflicting session attributes.  You may need to rethink things.

Comment: ah it seems that perhabs its not my misunderstanding of socket eventlisteners spamming, which i was talking about in comment to highter reply...