# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. error received after refreshing a get request

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt

The following code works as expected the first time it executes. The second time through it fails with the following error:
`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`
Basically, i'm trying to return a message from a series of published mqtt topics. I've tried several ways to do this but am at a loss as to this behavior. The code below shows an attempt using promises as detailed in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) MDN article. I also tried using async / await (i can post this code as well if needed).

**Concept**
a get request arrives from a webpage, this triggers a mqtt message to be published to a local broker. a separate endpoint is listening for this topic. In this case a raspberry pi with a connected webcam. The topic is received the rpi does it's thing and publishes a return message with a url as it's data. the initial mqtt publisher is listening for this response and fires res.json() in response.
This works the first time, when i refresh the webpage it fails with Can't headers after they are sent. How does one reset res? It appears that this is the case.

punchitRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const punchitRoute = express.Router();
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.88.54:1883');

client.subscribe('returned', function(){
    console.log('subscribed');
})

async function img(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{ client.on('message', function(topic, url){
            const message = {
                url: url.toString(),
                name: "garfield",
                date: Date.now()
            }
        return message;
        })
     })

}

 punchitRoute.get('/', async function(req, res){
    const mess = await img();
    console.log(mess);
    res.json(mess);
});

module.exports = punchitRoute;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const punchit = require('./routes/punchitRoute');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false })); 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    res.json({
      name: "Express application",
      message: "welcome to punchit"
    })
  });

app.use('/api/punchit', punchit);

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6040;
  app.listen(PORT);
  console.log('server started on: ', PORT);
```

My guess is that i am missing a basic fact of life regarding requests using express.
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: For starters, your `img()` function never calls `resolve()` to resolve its promise.

Comment: Then, secondly, everytime you call `img()`, you add yet another event handler for `client.on('message', ...)`.  Those will pile up and you will have duplicates and you will try to respond to the same message multiple times.  Generally promises are not a good match for event handlers because there are sequencing issues if the function is called multiple times, but if you were going to attempt to use them that way, you have to remove the event handler after it fires.  Even then, there are still issues to solve.

Comment: thanks for the response. is it better in this case to use async / await?

Comment: Honestly, your code is so confused that I can't really advise what you should do.  You would need to provide a complete description of what you're trying to accomplish (in words, not code) so we could advise from scratch what would be the best implementation.  `async/await` isn't going to fix any of the things I've commented on.

Comment: confused is a kind way to put it. The code above is a mistake, the file i copied was edited without testing, when i finally realized i wasn't calling this file in testing and switched it over, the code above failed in several areas. I'll re-post edits to the code and re-describe the objective.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jfriend00 for pointing me in the right direction. First the code posted was completely incorrect. I was super confused with this and subsequently renamed the file punchitRoute file to keep working on it in a different approach, but forgot to rename the required file in server.js! That was a bonehead mistake.

The 2nd comment about event handler for `client.on('message', ...)` gave me the hint i needed to look into the event loop.

The idea here was to snap an image from a webcam using mqtt from a get request. The get request comes into the express server, triggers a subscription to a topic called *'**returned'*** and publishes to a topic called *'**sunrise'*** with the a message of ***'click'***.

There is a separate endpoint on a local network and listening to a local mqtt broker (both shared with the express server) that is listening for the ***'sunrise'*** topic. This endpoint broadcast's ***'returned'*** after the image has been saved into an S3 bucket and send the url of the image as the message back to the server running the get request. The mqtt functions work well, the issue I had was with the response event not terminating at the conclusion of the response. For this too work, several things had to change.

1. moved the res.send into a function called after client.on *(this didn't completely work, it allowed the send to happen but still returned the error)*
2. added event emitters to see which event were being triggered over and over again *(this gave me some visibility into what was happening, but still didn't remove the error)*
3. researched additional mqtt libraries *(ended up staying with async-mqtt)*
4. added client.unsubscribe for both topics after the res.send function *(this had no effect)*
5. finally found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269285/nodejs-how-to-make-functions-happen-just-once) answer which helped me to realize this whole time i could've just called client.once!

here's the code for the get request:

```
punchitRoute.get('/', async function(req, res){
//adding event listner 'send'
mqEvent.on('send', function(){
    console.log('added send');
});

let sendit = function(url){
    'send', //emmitting 'send'
    res.status(200).send(
        '<img src='+url.toString()+' />'+
        '<h1>PUNCHED!</h1>'+
        '<p>'+
        'name: garfield <br/> time: '+moment(Date.now()).tz("America/Louisville").format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
    }

client.subscribe('returned', function(){
    console.log('subscribed');
});
client.publish('sunrise', 'click');
//changed this to .once and no more errors
await client.once('message', async function callout(topic, url){
    try {

            mqEvent.on('message', function(){
                console.log('added message');
            });

        sendit(url.toString());

            // console.log(res);
        client.unsubscribe('returned', ()=>{
            console.log('unsubscribed');
        });
        client.unsubscribe('sunrise', ()=>{
            console.log('unsubscribed publish');
        });
        //clearing out the send event listeners
        mqEvent.removeAllListeners('send');
        console.log(mqEvent.listenerCount('send'));
        //clearing out the message event listeners
        mqEvent.removeAllListeners('message');

     } catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            console.log('error');
        }
    })
});
```

Hopefully this can someone else faced with a similar issue.